# Approximating the integral $\int_1^\frac{3}{2}\frac{\ln(x+1)-\ln(2)}{x-1}dx$ to accuracy of $0.001$

Tags: approximation, approximate-integration

I need to approximate the integral $\int\limits_1^\frac{3}{2}\frac{\ln(x+1)-\ln(2)}{x-1}dx$ with an accuracy of $0.001.$

How don't know how I can do it, since the integrand doesn't have an elementary antiderivative, and because it's an improper integral.

I thought about trying to use Taylor Series, but I can't expand the $\ln(1+x)$ because $|x|>1.$

How can I do it?

Comment: I wouldn't worry about the integral being improper (just take the integrand to be $1/2$ at 1, which is its limit there.)    If this is for a class, have you seen any methods of numerical integration?  If so, which ones?

Comment: Do you need methods for integrating integrals such that or just this value? If you only need the value for some clarification for example, the easiest method would be to use a computer-algebra system like Wolfram-Alpha. If you are lucky, there is a specific class of functions that describe your value and that can be evaluated via a series. E.g. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+%28ln%28x%2B1%29-ln%282%29%29%2F%28x-1%29+dx+from+x+%3D+1+to+x+%3D3%2F2

Comment: Seeing as the integrand is a difference quotient, perhaps the mean value theorem could be of some use here?

Comment: This can be reduced to $\int_0^{1/4}\frac{\log(1+x)}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x=\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty(-1)^{k-1}\frac{(1/4)^k}{k^2}$. The fourth term is $-\frac1{4096}$, so we only need to take the first three terms, which gives $\frac{17}{72}$.

Comment: @robjohn Which  substitution you used?

Comment: @Daniel: I have added an answer with the details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$I=\int_{1}^{3/2} \frac{\ln(1+x)-\ln 2}{x-1}dx= \int_{0}^{1/2} \frac{\ln (1+u/2)}{u} du.$$
We have used $u=x-1$. Next use $\ln(1+z) \approx z-z^2/2+z^3/3$ for an accuracy of about $0.01$, then
$$I_{approx}=\int_{0}^{1/2} [1/2-u/8+u^2/(24)] du=[u/2-u^2/(16)+u^3/(72)]_{u=0}^{1/2}=\frac{17}{72}=0.2361$$
Whereas its exact value as per Mathematica is $0.2359$.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{align}
\int_1^{3/2}\frac{\log(x+1)-\log(2)}{x-1}\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\int_0^{1/2}\frac{\log(x+2)-\log(2)}x\,\mathrm{d}x\tag1\\
&=\int_0^{1/4}\frac{\log(x+1)}x\,\mathrm{d}x\tag2\\
&=\int_0^{1/4}\sum_{k=1}^\infty(-1)^{k-1}\frac{x^{k-1}}k\,\mathrm{d}x\tag3\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty(-1)^{k-1}\frac{(1/4)^k}{k^2}\tag4
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: substitute $x\mapsto x+1$
$(2)$: substitute $x\mapsto2x$
$(3)$: use the Taylor series for $\frac{\log(1+x)}x$
$(4)$: integrate term by term

For $k=4$, $(-1)^{k-1}\frac{(1/4)^k}{k^2}=-\frac1{4096}$, so the Alternating Series Test says we only need to include the first three terms:
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^3(-1)^{k-1}\frac{(1/4)^k}{k^2}
&=\frac{17}{72}\tag5\\
&\approx0.236111\tag6
\end{align}
$$
Adding more terms, we get that
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^\infty(-1)^{k-1}\frac{(1/4)^k}{k^2}
&=-\operatorname{Li}_2(-1/4)\tag7\\
&\approx0.235900297686\tag8
\end{align}
$$
Thus, the error is $0.000211\le\frac1{4096}$ as the Alternating Series Test promised.

Comment: Lambert again ! Cheers :-)

Answer (score 0):

To your Taylor series idea:  Since $x \in [1,3/2]$, $x+1 \in [2,5/2]$  But this means $\frac{1}{x+1} \in [2/5, 1/2]$ which *is* in the radius of convergence of the usual Taylor series of the natural logarithm (centered at $1$).  So use
$$  \ln(x+1) = - \ln \frac{1}{x+1}  $$
to rewrite your integrand to use your Taylor series.

Alternatively, you could construct the Taylor series centered at, say, $2$:
$$  \ln 2 + \frac{x-2}{2} - \frac{(x-2)^2}{8} + \frac{(x-2)^3}{24} - {\dots}  \text{.}  $$  Those numerators are upper bounded by powers of $1/2$ for your interval or integration and the denominators are approximately doubling at each step, so you shouldn't need more than about six terms...

Regarding having an elementary antiderivative:  The antiderivative of the integrand is $$\ln(1/2 - x/2) \ln (1/2+x/2) \mathrm{Li}_2(x/2+1/2)  \text{,}  $$
where $\mathrm{Li}_2$ is the [dilogarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm#Dilogarithm).  There are many techniques for evaluating the dilogarithm and the link provides a few starting points you could use.

Another method is to approximate with a (finite) Riemann sum.  It is elementary calculus (optimization) to show that the the derivative of the integrand has bounded magnitude.  (Just examining the graph of the derivative of the integrand, the magnitude is bounded by $0.13$ and this visual estimate can be improved by using actual calculation).  Then an [error bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_integration#Conservative_(a_priori)_error_estimation) on the evenly-spaced $n$ term Riemann sum approximation to the integral, is $\frac{1}{2n}(0.13)$.  This is less than $0.001$ when $n > 65$, so look at (the right Riemann sum)
$$  \sum_{n=1}^{65} f \left( 1 + \frac{n}{65}(3/2 - 1)\right) \cdot \frac{3/2 - 1}{65}  \text{,}  $$
where $f(x)$ is your integrand.  The error in using this series is actually $0.000\,206{\dots}$.

Answer (score 0):

Developed as an infinite series around $x=1$
$$\frac{\ln(x+1)-\ln(2)}{x-1}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n }{2^{n+1}(n+1)}(x-1)^n$$
$$I=\int_1^\frac{3}{2}\frac{\ln(x+1)-\ln(2)}{x-1}dx=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n }{2^{2 (n+1)}\,(n+1)^2}$$ So, if you want an accuracy of $\epsilon$, write
$$I=\sum_{n=0}^p\frac{(-1)^n }{2^{2 (n+1)}\,(n+1)^2}+\sum_{n=p+1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n }{2^{2 (n+1)}\,(n+1)^2}$$ and since this is an alternating series, you search for $p$ such that
$$R_p=\frac{1}{2^{2 (p+2)}\,(p+2)^2} \leq \epsilon$$ that is to say
$$p=-2+\frac{W\left(t\right)}{\log (2)} \qquad \text{where} \qquad t=\frac{\log (2)}{\sqrt{\epsilon }}$$ where appears [Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) and, as usual, you will need to use $\lceil p \rceil$.

For the estimation of $W(t)$, we can use the expansion given in the Wikipedia page
$$W(t)=L_1-L_2+\frac{L_2}{L_1}+\frac{(L_2-2) L_2}{2 L_1^2}+\frac{(2 L_2^2-9L_2+6) L_2}{6 L_1^3}+ ...$$ where $L_1=\log(t)$ and $L_2=\log(L_1)$.

If $\epsilon=0.001$, this will give $p=1.2725$ and then $p=2$. Checking the various values of $R_p$
$$R_1=\frac 1 {576} \qquad R_2=\frac 1 {4096} \qquad R_3=\frac 1 {25600} \qquad R_4=\frac 1 {147456}$$

So, using $p=2$, the approximate value of the integral is
$$\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{64}+\frac{1}{576}=\frac{17}{72}\approx 0.236111$$ while its exact value is
$$\frac{1}{6} \left(-6 \text{Li}_2\left(\frac{4}{5}\right)+\pi ^2+3 \log ^2(4)-3 \log
   ^2(5)\right)\approx 0.235900$$.